# Programmatically list supported languages for AWS Transcribe

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, amazon-transcribe

AWS lists supported languages for Transcribe here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/supported-languages.html

Short of parsing the documentation page, is there any way to get a list of these languages programmatically?

[ListLanguageModels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-transcribe/classes/listlanguagemodelscommand.html) seemed promising, but it's only for custom models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all available languages in AWS JS SDK directly.  Check the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/clients/client-transcribe/src/models/models_0.ts#L110-L149).

```js
// For regular transcription...
// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-transcribe/enums/languagecode.html
TranscribeClient.LanguageCode

// For streaming transcription...
// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-transcribe-streaming/enums/languagecode.html
TranscribeStreamingClient.LanguageCode
```

Comment: Nice, good find.  Do you see any similar list for the languages supported for streaming transcription?  I see `CLMLanguageCode`, but doesn't seem to completely match.

Comment: Found it!  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/2c2f92abaf6558299c57e57a92d66c1e7df77b72/clients/client-transcribe-streaming/src/models/models_0.ts#L844